# From where is GitHub taking the time of the push?

Tags: git, github

If I change time on my computer, then commit and push, I saw github takes the time that it was set on my pc when I commited my changes. Is there a way to make github show the real hour/date?

Answer (score 3):

The time of the push doesn't matter; you can push the same commit many times on many remote repositories. It is not stored anywhere.

Each commit stores two timestamps: the time when it was created (author date) and the time when it was applied (committer date). These times are identical when the commit is created. The committer date changes when the commit is amended, applied from a patch, cherry-picked, rebased etc.
These timestamps are, by default, generated using the current time on the computer where the commit is created/updated but you can [override them if needed](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables).

Read more about the difference between author and committer in the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History#pretty_format).

Comment: Note that you can also override one or both time stamps when you make the commit object. Using the computer's idea of the current time is merely the default. There are some fun (sort of fun, maybe) effects you can get by dating a commit well into the future.